# ENOMEM (Out of memory) and out of stack in ubt_x32a64_al

Tags: x86, out-of-memory, emulation, mmap, ulimit

following with the new exagear x86_64 can be download it from here https://threedots.ovh/blog/2021/01/huawei-exagear-x86_64-apps-on-arm64/
i get error with running

```
.../files/home # ./ubt_x32a64_al

Failed to initialize ubtipc.

[Pid 29870] ubt_Error at ubt_al.cc:842

Backtrace:
  0x7800118800
  0x78000655a0
  0x780011fb64
  Backtrace end (frame 0x0 is out of current stack)
```

with strace

```
.../files/home # strace ./ubt_x32a64_al
execve("./ubt_x32a64_al", ["./ubt_x32a64_al"], [/* 11 vars */]) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff00000, 524288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0) = 0x7ffff00000
mmap(0x880000000000, 104, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Out of memory)
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "Failed to initialize ubtipc.\n", 29Failed to initialize ubtipc.
) = 29
getpid()                                = 29894
write(2, "\n[Pid 29894] ubt_Error at ubt_al"..., 40
[Pid 29894] ubt_Error at ubt_al.cc:842
) = 40
write(2, "\nBacktrace:\n", 12
Backtrace:
)          = 12
write(2, "  0x7800118800\n", 15  0x7800118800
)        = 15
write(2, "  0x78000655a0\n", 15  0x78000655a0
)        = 15
write(2, "  0x780011fb64\n", 15  0x780011fb64
)        = 15
write(2, "  Backtrace end (frame 0x0 is ou"..., 52  Backtrace end (frame 0x0 is out of current stack)
) = 52
fsync(2)                                = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

what is the issue and how to fix it? ulimit doesnot work
here is some info about my mem

```
.../files/home # prlimit
RESOURCE   DESCRIPTION                             SOFT      HARD UNITS
AS         address space limit                unlimited unlimited bytes
CORE       max core file size                         0 unlimited bytes
CPU        CPU time                           unlimited unlimited seconds
DATA       max data size                      unlimited unlimited bytes
FSIZE      max file size                      unlimited unlimited bytes
LOCKS      max number of file locks held      unlimited unlimited locks
MEMLOCK    max locked-in-memory address space     65536     65536 bytes
MSGQUEUE   max bytes in POSIX mqueues            819200    819200 bytes
NICE       max nice prio allowed to raise            40        40
NOFILE     max number of open files                1024      4096 files
NPROC      max number of processes                 7312      7312 processes
RSS        max resident set size              unlimited unlimited bytes
RTPRIO     max real-time priority                     0         0
RTTIME     timeout for real-time tasks        unlimited unlimited microsecs
SIGPENDING max number of pending signals           7312      7312 signals
STACK      max stack size                       8388608 unlimited bytes
```

```
root@localhost:/opt/exagear/bin# strace ./ubt_x32a64_al
execve("./ubt_x32a64_al", ["./ubt_x32a64_al"], 0x7ffffffbf0 /* 14 vars */) = 0
mmap(0x7ffff00000, 524288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0) = 0x7ffff00000
mmap(0x880000000000, 104, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "Failed to initialize ubtipc.\n", 29Failed to initialize ubtipc.
) = 29
getpid()                                = 31980
write(2, "\n[Pid 31980] ubt_Error at ubt_al"..., 40
[Pid 31980] ubt_Error at ubt_al.cc:915
) = 40
write(2, "\nBacktrace: ", 12
Backtrace: )           = 12
readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/exe", "/opt/exagear/bin/ubt_x32a64_al", 255) = 30
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/exagear/bin/ubt_x32a64_al.debug", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\34\373\21\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 337528, SEEK_SET)              = 337528
read(3, "\21\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0x\"\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 64
lseek(3, 336504, SEEK_SET)              = 336504
read(3, "\0.symtab\0.strtab\0.shstrtab\0.init"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 336632, SEEK_SET)              = 336632
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 960
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
lseek(3, 440, SEEK_SET)                 = 440
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\1\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0@y\22\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\270\17\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\334\10\0\0\2\0\2\0\330\17\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "L\16\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\321\17\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0q\16\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\272\24\0\0\1\0\n\0\20\200\2#x\0\0\0p\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\360\216\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\31\0\0\2\0\2\0\210\220\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\231\34\0\0\2\0\2\0\250\331\3\0x\0\0\0\300\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\260\34\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\274\0\0\0\0\0\0\0006 \0\0\2\0\2\0\250\4\4\0x\0\0\0\210\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\230h\23\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\250D\22\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\223(\0\0\1\0\4\0000\251\23\0x\0\0\0(\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\316(\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0f0\0\0\1\0\4\0\360\217\23\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "H\245\5\0x\0\0\0\324\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\177:\0\0\2\0\2\0 \246\5\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "2E\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\314\5\0x\0\0\0\344\0\0\0\0\0\0\0oE\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\244\0\0\0\0\0\0\0/P\0\0\2\0\2\0000\377\5\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220\377\23\0x\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\251\\\0\0\1\0\4\0\240\377\23\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\365f\0\0\2\0\2\0\320!\6\0x\0\0\0h\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-g\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0P\301\24\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`'\25\0x\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0`'\25\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\306{\0\0\2\0\2\0\30}\t\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\6\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\30\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\204\0\0\2\0\2\0\200#\n\0x\0\0\0\24\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\340]\v\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\303\210\0\0\2\0\2\0\220b\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\26\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\250\v\30\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\361\377"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\230\223\0\0\2\0\2\0\270\3\r\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "@\204\25\0x\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\t\0p\367\34\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "C\237\0\0\2\0\2\0\370\346\r\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0h\237\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0$\244\0\0\2\0\2\0\330c\20\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\350\254\30\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0W\247\0\0\4\0\361\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "D\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\22\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0[\252\0\0\0\0\361\377"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\205\255\0\0\0\0\2\0\220\361\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\21\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "i\255\0\0\0\0\2\0\270\365\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0v\255\0\0\0\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\17\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\310\367\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\266\256\0\0\4\0\361\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "|\264\0\0\22\2\2\0 {\5\0x\0\0\0\254\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\310\264\0\0\21\2\n\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "d\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\340\277\0\0\22\2\2\0\320\307\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220y\17\0x\0\0\0t\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\334\313\0\0\22\2\2\0\360\r\f\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\r\325\0\0\22\2\2\0\0\323\7\0x\0\0\0\360\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\216\325\0\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "$\1\0\0\0\0\0\0h\340\0\0\22\2\2\0 3\t\0x\0\0\0`\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`E\v\0x\0\0\0\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0]\353\0\0\22\2\2\0x\262\10\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, ">\365\0\0\22\2\2\0\220L\7\0x\0\0\0L\3\0\0\0\0\0\0a\365\0\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\340\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\345\0\1\0\22\2\2\0\330Y\n\0x\0\0\0\210\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "(^\4\0x\0\0\0|\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\f\1\0\22\2\2\0\340\345\7\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`\25\1\0\22\2\2\0P\225\t\0x\0\0\0p\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\261\25\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f!\1\0\22\2\2\0H\300\f\0x\0\0\0\220\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "8\333\t\0x\0\0\0\300\0\0\0\0\0\0\0|,\1\0\22\0\2\0\300\t\5\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "#7\1\0\22\2\2\0\360\260\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2707\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\304\0\0\0\0\0\0\0jA\1\0\22\2\2\0\230\340\v\0x\0\0\0 \1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "p\303\t\0x\0\0\0l\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\252L\1\0\22\2\2\0P\330\r\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\232V\1\0\22\2\2\0pM\v\0x\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\266V\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, " \330\0\0\0\0\0\0\310a\1\0\22\2\2\0\2209\t\0x\0\0\0\220\4\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\304\334\1#x\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\340l\1\0\22\2\2\0\260\342\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "~v\1\0\22\2\2\0\300^\3\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\217v\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\234\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\277\200\1\0\22\2\2\0\260\251\f\0x\0\0\0\354\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\10)\3\0x\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\350\213\1\0\22\2\2\0\250\222\4\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\266\227\1\0\22\2\2\0XK\5\0x\0\0\0D\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\230\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 209787, SEEK_SET)              = 209787
read(3, "_ZN12dcdx86_Instr17gLogicOpcodeP"..., 1024) = 1024
write(2, "    0x7800127278: <_ZN12dcdx86_I"..., 64    0x7800127278: <_ZN12dcdx86_Instr17gLogicOpcodePropsE+0xb08>
) = 64
lseek(3, 440, SEEK_SET)                 = 440
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\1\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0@y\22\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\270\17\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\334\10\0\0\2\0\2\0\330\17\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "L\16\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\321\17\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0q\16\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\272\24\0\0\1\0\n\0\20\200\2#x\0\0\0p\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\360\216\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\31\0\0\2\0\2\0\210\220\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\231\34\0\0\2\0\2\0\250\331\3\0x\0\0\0\300\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\260\34\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\274\0\0\0\0\0\0\0006 \0\0\2\0\2\0\250\4\4\0x\0\0\0\210\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\230h\23\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\250D\22\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\223(\0\0\1\0\4\0000\251\23\0x\0\0\0(\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\316(\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0f0\0\0\1\0\4\0\360\217\23\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "H\245\5\0x\0\0\0\324\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\177:\0\0\2\0\2\0 \246\5\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "2E\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\314\5\0x\0\0\0\344\0\0\0\0\0\0\0oE\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\244\0\0\0\0\0\0\0/P\0\0\2\0\2\0000\377\5\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220\377\23\0x\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\251\\\0\0\1\0\4\0\240\377\23\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\365f\0\0\2\0\2\0\320!\6\0x\0\0\0h\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-g\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0P\301\24\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`'\25\0x\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0`'\25\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\306{\0\0\2\0\2\0\30}\t\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\6\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\30\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\204\0\0\2\0\2\0\200#\n\0x\0\0\0\24\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\340]\v\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\303\210\0\0\2\0\2\0\220b\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\26\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\250\v\30\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\361\377"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\230\223\0\0\2\0\2\0\270\3\r\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "@\204\25\0x\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\t\0p\367\34\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "C\237\0\0\2\0\2\0\370\346\r\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0h\237\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0$\244\0\0\2\0\2\0\330c\20\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\350\254\30\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0W\247\0\0\4\0\361\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "D\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\22\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0[\252\0\0\0\0\361\377"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\205\255\0\0\0\0\2\0\220\361\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\21\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "i\255\0\0\0\0\2\0\270\365\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0v\255\0\0\0\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\17\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\310\367\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\266\256\0\0\4\0\361\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "|\264\0\0\22\2\2\0 {\5\0x\0\0\0\254\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\310\264\0\0\21\2\n\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "d\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\340\277\0\0\22\2\2\0\320\307\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220y\17\0x\0\0\0t\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\334\313\0\0\22\2\2\0\360\r\f\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\r\325\0\0\22\2\2\0\0\323\7\0x\0\0\0\360\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\216\325\0\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "$\1\0\0\0\0\0\0h\340\0\0\22\2\2\0 3\t\0x\0\0\0`\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`E\v\0x\0\0\0\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0]\353\0\0\22\2\2\0x\262\10\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, ">\365\0\0\22\2\2\0\220L\7\0x\0\0\0L\3\0\0\0\0\0\0a\365\0\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\340\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\345\0\1\0\22\2\2\0\330Y\n\0x\0\0\0\210\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "(^\4\0x\0\0\0|\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\f\1\0\22\2\2\0\340\345\7\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`\25\1\0\22\2\2\0P\225\t\0x\0\0\0p\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\261\25\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f!\1\0\22\2\2\0H\300\f\0x\0\0\0\220\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "8\333\t\0x\0\0\0\300\0\0\0\0\0\0\0|,\1\0\22\0\2\0\300\t\5\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "#7\1\0\22\2\2\0\360\260\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2707\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\304\0\0\0\0\0\0\0jA\1\0\22\2\2\0\230\340\v\0x\0\0\0 \1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "p\303\t\0x\0\0\0l\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\252L\1\0\22\2\2\0P\330\r\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 189923, SEEK_SET)              = 189923
read(3, "_ZN12dcdarm_Instr21gLogicOpcodeP"..., 1024) = 1024
write(2, "    0x780013bfa4: <_ZN12dcdarm_I"..., 69    0x780013bfa4: <_ZN12dcdarm_Instr21gLogicOpcodePrintInfoE+0x154c>
) = 69
lseek(3, 440, SEEK_SET)                 = 440
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\1\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0@y\22\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\270\17\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\334\10\0\0\2\0\2\0\330\17\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "L\16\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\321\17\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0q\16\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\272\24\0\0\1\0\n\0\20\200\2#x\0\0\0p\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\360\216\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\31\0\0\2\0\2\0\210\220\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\231\34\0\0\2\0\2\0\250\331\3\0x\0\0\0\300\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\260\34\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\274\0\0\0\0\0\0\0006 \0\0\2\0\2\0\250\4\4\0x\0\0\0\210\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\230h\23\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\250D\22\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\223(\0\0\1\0\4\0000\251\23\0x\0\0\0(\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\316(\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0f0\0\0\1\0\4\0\360\217\23\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "H\245\5\0x\0\0\0\324\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\177:\0\0\2\0\2\0 \246\5\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "2E\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\314\5\0x\0\0\0\344\0\0\0\0\0\0\0oE\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\244\0\0\0\0\0\0\0/P\0\0\2\0\2\0000\377\5\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220\377\23\0x\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\251\\\0\0\1\0\4\0\240\377\23\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\365f\0\0\2\0\2\0\320!\6\0x\0\0\0h\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-g\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 131454, SEEK_SET)              = 131454
read(3, "_ZL19ulibc_FindArgumentsPKcSt9__"..., 1024) = 1024
write(2, "    0x7800068910: <_ZL19ulibc_Fi"..., 83    0x7800068910: <_ZL19ulibc_FindArgumentsPKcSt9__va_listPP11ulibc_Arg_tPm+0x9b8>
) = 83
lseek(3, 440, SEEK_SET)                 = 440
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\1\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0@y\22\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\270\17\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\334\10\0\0\2\0\2\0\330\17\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "L\16\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\321\17\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0q\16\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\272\24\0\0\1\0\n\0\20\200\2#x\0\0\0p\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\360\216\3\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\31\0\0\2\0\2\0\210\220\3\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\231\34\0\0\2\0\2\0\250\331\3\0x\0\0\0\300\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\260\34\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\274\0\0\0\0\0\0\0006 \0\0\2\0\2\0\250\4\4\0x\0\0\0\210\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\230h\23\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\250D\22\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\223(\0\0\1\0\4\0000\251\23\0x\0\0\0(\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\316(\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0f0\0\0\1\0\4\0\360\217\23\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "H\245\5\0x\0\0\0\324\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\177:\0\0\2\0\2\0 \246\5\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "2E\0\0\2\0\2\0\30\314\5\0x\0\0\0\344\0\0\0\0\0\0\0oE\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\244\0\0\0\0\0\0\0/P\0\0\2\0\2\0000\377\5\0x\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220\377\23\0x\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\251\\\0\0\1\0\4\0\240\377\23\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\365f\0\0\2\0\2\0\320!\6\0x\0\0\0h\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-g\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0P\301\24\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`'\25\0x\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\4\0`'\25\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\306{\0\0\2\0\2\0\30}\t\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\6\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\30\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\204\0\0\2\0\2\0\200#\n\0x\0\0\0\24\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\340]\v\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\303\210\0\0\2\0\2\0\220b\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\26\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\250\v\30\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\361\377"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\230\223\0\0\2\0\2\0\270\3\r\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "@\204\25\0x\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\t\0p\367\34\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "C\237\0\0\2\0\2\0\370\346\r\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0h\237\0\0\2\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0$\244\0\0\2\0\2\0\330c\20\0x\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\350\254\30\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0W\247\0\0\4\0\361\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "D\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\22\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0[\252\0\0\0\0\361\377"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\205\255\0\0\0\0\2\0\220\361\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\21\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "i\255\0\0\0\0\2\0\270\365\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0v\255\0\0\0\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\252\0\0\0\0\361\377\17\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\310\367\21\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\266\256\0\0\4\0\361\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "|\264\0\0\22\2\2\0 {\5\0x\0\0\0\254\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\310\264\0\0\21\2\n\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "d\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\340\277\0\0\22\2\2\0\320\307\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220y\17\0x\0\0\0t\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\334\313\0\0\22\2\2\0\360\r\f\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\r\325\0\0\22\2\2\0\0\323\7\0x\0\0\0\360\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\216\325\0\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "$\1\0\0\0\0\0\0h\340\0\0\22\2\2\0 3\t\0x\0\0\0`\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`E\v\0x\0\0\0\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0]\353\0\0\22\2\2\0x\262\10\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, ">\365\0\0\22\2\2\0\220L\7\0x\0\0\0L\3\0\0\0\0\0\0a\365\0\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\340\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\345\0\1\0\22\2\2\0\330Y\n\0x\0\0\0\210\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "(^\4\0x\0\0\0|\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\f\1\0\22\2\2\0\340\345\7\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`\25\1\0\22\2\2\0P\225\t\0x\0\0\0p\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\261\25\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f!\1\0\22\2\2\0H\300\f\0x\0\0\0\220\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "8\333\t\0x\0\0\0\300\0\0\0\0\0\0\0|,\1\0\22\0\2\0\300\t\5\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "#7\1\0\22\2\2\0\360\260\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2707\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\304\0\0\0\0\0\0\0jA\1\0\22\2\2\0\230\340\v\0x\0\0\0 \1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "p\303\t\0x\0\0\0l\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\252L\1\0\22\2\2\0P\330\r\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\232V\1\0\22\2\2\0pM\v\0x\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\266V\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, " \330\0\0\0\0\0\0\310a\1\0\22\2\2\0\2209\t\0x\0\0\0\220\4\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\304\334\1#x\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\340l\1\0\22\2\2\0\260\342\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "~v\1\0\22\2\2\0\300^\3\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\217v\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\234\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\277\200\1\0\22\2\2\0\260\251\f\0x\0\0\0\354\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\10)\3\0x\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\350\213\1\0\22\2\2\0\250\222\4\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\266\227\1\0\22\2\2\0XK\5\0x\0\0\0D\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\230\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "4\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\260\241\1\0\22\2\2\0\300\237\t\0x\0\0\0t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\260\1\0x\0\0\0\204\0\0\0\0\0\0\0x\253\1\0\22\2\2\0\340\343\4\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "*\266\1\0\22\2\2\0\350G\2\0x\0\0\0X\2\0\0\0\0\0\0e\266\1\0\22\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, ",\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\235\301\1\0\22\2\2\0\210L\10\0x\0\0\0\344\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\240\203\2\0x\0\0\0<\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\372\314\1\0\22\2\2\0XM\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "N\330\1\0\22\2\2\0\300y\5\0x\0\0\0`\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\227\330\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\321\341\1\0\22\2\2\0X\1\16\0x\0\0\0\4\33\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`\2\35\0x\0\0\0p\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\262\354\1\0\22\2\2\0\10\210\7\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\25\370\1\0\22\0\2\0\270T\6\0x\0\0\0\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0)\370\1\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\200\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\3\2\0\22\2\2\0\230\275\4\0x\0\0\0,\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\20\235\17\0x\0\0\0\10\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\\\f\2\0\21\2\t\0 C\34\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\26\27\2\0\22\2\2\0\320\272\7\0x\0\0\0\230\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\203\27\2\0\21\2\n\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\364\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\351!\2\0\22\2\2\0p\341\0\0x\0\0\0\310\2\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "`\317\t\0x\0\0\0\264\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\306-\2\0\22\2\2\0x\276\f\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\2676\2\0\22\2\2\0\30\240\17\0x\0\0\0\230\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\3476\2\0\22\0\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "D\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\356A\2\0\22\2\2\0\10\270\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\220\357\2\0x\0\0\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\375L\2\0\21\2\n\0\20\34\35\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\237W\2\0\22\2\2\0\230\32\7\0x\0\0\0H\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\312W\2\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "l\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\334a\2\0\22\2\2\0\260\332\17\0x\0\0\0\20\2\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "p\10\10\0x\0\0\08\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\276l\2\0\22\2\2\0@\370\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\265u\2\0\21\0\4\0 \t\26\0x\0\0\0(\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\310u\2\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "X\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\314\177\2\0\22\2\2\08\0\f\0x\0\0\0\254\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0Q\t\0x\0\0\0\254\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\245\211\2\0\22\2\2\0\310Z\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\372\223\2\0\22\2\2\0\230.\1\0x\0\0\0\300\2\0\0\0\0\0\0007\224\2\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\320\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\377\234\2\0\22\2\2\0`\360\16\0x\0\0\0\200\2\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\300\235\0\0x\0\0\0\300\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\30\250\2\0\22\2\2\0\210`\4\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "i\263\2\0\21\2\t\0\360\277\31\0x\0\0\0\340\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\216\263\2\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "l\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\240\275\2\0\22\2\2\0\330R\4\0x\0\0\0L\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\310\253\v\0x\0\0\0T\0\0\0\0\0\0\0+\310\2\0\22\2\2\0000x\f\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\17\323\2\0\22\2\2\0x\20\20\0x\0\0\0\354\0\0\0\0\0\0\0*\323\2\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\234\334\2\0\22\2\2\0@\376\6\0x\0\0\0\260\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "P\311\7\0x\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\365\347\2\0\22\2\2\0\20F\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, ",\363\2\0\22\2\2\0`\222\4\0x\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0I\363\2\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\250\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\23\376\2\0\22\2\2\0\210{\21\0x\0\0\0\264\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\250\243\2\0x\0\0\0\300\0\0\0\0\0\0\0U\10\3\0\22\2\2\0x\262\t\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "P\22\3\0\22\2\2\0`D\n\0x\0\0\0\274\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\251\22\3\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\202\33\3\0\22\2\2\0\220X\4\0x\0\0\0L\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "x\251\t\0x\0\0\0\310\0\0\0\0\0\0\0X'\3\0\22\2\2\0(\270\10\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\3750\3\0\22\2\2\0\340\351\4\0x\0\0\0D\0\0\0\0\0\0\0c1\3\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\254\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\21;\3\0\22\2\2\0xw\0\0x\0\0\0\20\3\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "@\377\1\0x\0\0\0\220\4\0\0\0\0\0\0EF\3\0\22\2\2\0 F\v\0x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\270O\3\0\22\2\2\0\0o\3\0x\0\0\0\304\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\313O\3\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "0\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\377Y\3\0\22\2\2\0\330<\2\0x\0\0\0\344\1\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "x}\5\0x\0\0\0\260\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Be\3\0\21\2\n\0`C\2#x\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "1q\3\0\22\2\2\0P\10\f\0x\0\0\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Lq\3\0\22\2\2\0"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\374z\3\0\22\2\2\0\270F\v\0x\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
lseek(3, 333890, SEEK_SET)              = 333890
read(3, "_ZN12dcdx86_Instr21gLogicOpcodeP"..., 1024) = 1024
write(2, "    0x7800143484: <_ZN12dcdx86_I"..., 68    0x7800143484: <_ZN12dcdx86_Instr21gLogicOpcodePrintInfoE+0xde4>
) = 68
write(2, "  Backtrace end (frame 0x0 is ou"..., 52  Backtrace end (frame 0x0 is out of current stack)
) = 52
close(3)                                = 0
fsync(2)                                = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
root@localhost:/opt/exagear/bin#
```

```
root@localhost:/opt/exagear/bin# ./ubt_x32a64_al

Failed to initialize ubtipc.

[Pid 32540] ubt_Error at ubt_al.cc:915

Backtrace:
    0x7800127278: <_ZN12dcdx86_Instr17gLogicOpcodePropsE+0xb08>
    0x780013bfa4: <_ZN12dcdarm_Instr21gLogicOpcodePrintInfoE+0x154c>
    0x7800068910: <_ZL19ulibc_FindArgumentsPKcSt9__va_listPP11ulibc_Arg_tPm+0x9b8>
    0x7800143484: <_ZN12dcdx86_Instr21gLogicOpcodePrintInfoE+0xde4>
  Backtrace end (frame 0x0 is out of current stack)
root@localhost:/opt/exagear/bin#
```

Another output after i figure out i need to put .debug where the ubt is located to get full error output

Comment: This is not really a programmer question. I think it does not belong to Stackoverflow. Maybe look for a public forum for exagear

Answer (score 2):

`mmap(0x880000000000, 104, ...` looks weird to me.   The 2nd arg (`length`) should be a multiple of 4096, so I'm surprised at it returning ENOMEM instead of EINVAL.

Perhaps that's because `0x880000000000` isn't a canonical address for x86-64, unless you're on a system using PML5 for 57-bit virtual addresses (instead of the standard 48-bit that you get with the standard 4 levels of page tables).  `0x880000000000` has bit #48 set, so the high 16 bits should all be 1 for it to be correctly sign-extended.  (But then it would be a kernel address and user-space couldn't map it.)

So even with a valid (multiple-of-4096) `length` arg, this mmap couldn't work except on an Ice Lake or newer system with PML5 enabled.

The Linux [`mmap(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) says that should result in `EINVAL` as well: *`EINVAL` - We don't like `addr`, `length`, or `offset` (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).*

---

(Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  That's the programming reason why this `mmap` doesn't work, I think.  Questions about how to use some existing closed-source(?) software are off-topic, and I don't know anything about that program.)

Comment: Well that program is x86_64 emulator on arm64

Comment: @amera: Oh you're running this *on* ARM64?  I was assuming the reverse; running on x86_64 to emulate a phone, since the question is tagged `[x86]`, not `[x86-emulation] [arm64]`.  IDK what restrictions AArch64 has on valid addresses, but I think 104 is still not a valid page size.

Comment: I found this ``Q7: ExaGear Virtual address range used ？

A: The virtual address length used in the current version is 48bit, If the virtual address space allowed by the kernel is less than this length , Occurs at startup segment fault.

 

``

Comment: https://chowdera.com/2021/08/20210812015201661T.html